# Can't make a synchronous call in Angular

Tags: angular, asynchronous, subscribe

I have this problem with Angular I can't get through.

I'm making (just as an exercise) the frontend of a website that handles a movie database with users, comments, ratings, and so on. Users and comments are handled by different services and different databases.

I'm trying to make a component that displays, under a given movie description, each comment for that movie, with the name of the user who posted it.

The problem is, comments database does not store usernames, just user ids.

That's my `apiComment.model.ts`:

```
// Interface to get data by APIs
export interface CommentApiInterface {

   commentsResults : CommentsResultsInterface []
}

export interface CommentsResultsInterface {
    id : number;
    userId : number;
    movieId : number;
    body : string;
}
```

So I guess I should better pick the userId from the array of all comments for the movie I'm viewing details about and push them in a number array, then use a `for` loop to call all the user objects and store them in an array, then, using .map, copy all the `user.username` in a string array.

I created a component called `display-comments-for-single-movie`, this is its .ts file:

```
  commentsForMovie : CommentApiInterface;
  comments : CommentsResultsInterface [];
  user : UserInterface;
  users : UserInterface[];
  userIds : number[] = [];
  userNames : string[] = [];
  movieId : number;


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.movieId = this.route.snapshot.params['id']; // This correctly takes the movieId
    this.fetchEntry();
  }

  fetchEntry() {
    
    this.commentsService.getAllCommentsByMovieId(this.movieId).subscribe( (res: any) => {
    this.comments = res; // This retrieves all the comments with the given movieId
    this.userIds = this.comments.map(a => a.userId); // This creates an array of numbers with all the userIds in this.comments
    this.createCommentsWithUsernames(this.userIds);
    })
  }

  createCommentsWithUsernames(userIds){
    for (let userId of this.userIds){ 
      this.getUsernamesByUserId(userId); 
    }
  }

  getUsernamesByUserId(userId : number){
    console.log("userId: ", userId)
    this.usersService.getUserById(userId).subscribe((res : any) => {
      this.userNames.push(res.username);
      console.log(this.userNames)
    })
    
}
```

Here's where I get stuck: user names are indeed in the array, but they are not in the same order they are expected to be, i.e. the same as `this.userId`.

How can I handle this?

PS: I don't actually know what's the version of Angular I'm using (the last one, anyway, because a month ago I just barely know what Angular was), anyway `ng v` output is:

```
Angular CLI: 12.2.10
Node: 12.21.0
Package Manager: npm 7.23.0
OS: Linux x64

Angular: undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop will send a lot of request, and once a response is received it will update the array. But each API response do not have the same response time, so your array will be mixed up.

You have a lot of approaches, here some.

- One would be to send all API synchronously, and write each response before requesting the next one. But this approach would make the result and load time be very delayed and long for users.
- Another approach would be to make a specific API that return a list of user based on their id. so instead of doing 10 calls for 10 users, you would have 1 call that return the 10 users.
- For this specific code you set, and with the few changes possible you could simply map the id with the username (it might also be useful later on)

```
  userIds : number[] = [];
  userMap = new Map<string, string>();

  createCommentsWithUsernames(userIds){
    for (let userId of this.userIds){ 
      this.getUsernamesByUserId(userId); 
    }
  }

  getUsernamesByUserId(userId : number){
    console.log("userId: ", userId)
    this.usersService.getUserById(userId).subscribe((res : any) => {
      this.userMap.set(userId, res.username);
      console.log(this.userMap.get(userId))
    })
```

If your userIds are in order, you can then simply refer to them in your template `userMap[userId]` to display their username

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm sorry but it was actually not useful, because `this.userMap`, for some reason, only works in the `for` loop. The output of `console.log(this.userMap.values())`, after the last loop, is: `MapIterator {"User1", "User4", "User3", "User2"}` but when it comes back to the previous method, the same console.log output is `MapIterator {}` and I don't know how to get the datas out of it (even if the output of `console.log(this.userMap)` still shows the values are somehow present).

Comment: @CarcarloPravettoni https://hackinbits.com/articles/how-to-iterate-a-map-in-javascript---map-part-2